# Iterative goalseek function requires simplification for quicker program

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, iteration

I'm working on some code which takes two lists of data `x_list` and `y_list` which have a given number of entries `i`.

These lists are used in a goalseek calculation to gather a variable `STW` for `count` number of entries in the two lists.

However, this code fails to run (I'm guessing because its too heavy on CPU). Heres A simplified version of the code:

```
top = []
mid = []
bot = []

i = 0
while True:
    goal_seek = 0
    while True:
        goal_seek_top = (x_list[i] * (y_list[i] * goal_seek)
            

        goal_seek += 0.001
        if goal_seek_top >= 1:
            top.append(goal_seek_top)

    goal_seek = 0
    while True:
        goal_seek_mid = (x_list[i] * (y_list[i] * goal_seek)
                           
        goal_seek += 0.001
        if goal_seek_mid >= 1:
            mid.append(goal_seek_mid)

    goal_seek = 0
    while True:
        goal_seek_bot = (x_list[i] * (y_list[i] * goal_seek) 

        goal_seek += 0.001
        if goal_seek_mid >= 1:
            bot.append(STW_bot)

    i += 1
    if i == count:
        break
```

Is there a way to simplify this code so it runs smoother?

Comment: The code will never escape from the first inner `while` loop, because there is no `break` statement. I'm pretty sure, that there is a better algorithm for what you are trying to do, but I didn't quite understand your goals here. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: i += 1
    if i == count:
        break

was the break from the first while loop shown at the end.

Basically the x_list and y_list can be any given length depending on inputs. This is why I need to iterate through the STW goal seek function inorder to get the same number of STW variables as x and y variables.

The STW is found via a goal seek by slowly increasing tnhe value until the equation becomes greater than  or equal to 1.

Comment: @user8408080 does that make more sense?

The if STW statement acts as a break in the inner while loop.

Comment: The only `break` statement I see is in the outer `while` loop. I'm not familiar with the concepts of "STW" and "goal seek" as I never heard of them. I'm afraid I can't really help you with that

Comment: Edit to make  goal_seek clearer

Comment: But still, the first inner `while` loop will run forever (and if the others would be reachable, they would run forever, too), because, they never `break`.

Comment: @JosephJoeSoltan Do you need all 3 to run simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
top = []
mid = []
bot = []

i = 0
while True:
    global i
    goal_seek = 0
    goal_seek_top = (x_list[i] * (y_list[i] * goal_seek)
    goal_seek_mid = (x_list[i] * (y_list[i] * goal_seek)        
    goal_seek_bot = (x_list[i] * (y_list[i] * goal_seek)
    
    if goal_seek_top >= 1:
        top.append(goal_seek_top)
        break
    elif goal_seek_mid >= 1:
        mid.append(goal_seek_mid)
        break
    elif goal_seek_bot >= 1:
        bot.append(STW_bot)
        break
    else:
        goal_seek += 0.001
    
    # I dont know what i is doing so I suggest you change your break statement as given in the if statement above.
    i += 1
    if i == count:
        break
```